# Tooltip in geom_raster_interactive not returning correct value

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggiraph, geom-raster

I am trying to use geom_raster_interactive in ggiraph to create a map where I can view values of each grid cell using the tooltip function. However, when I set tooltip = value, the tooltip returns the same value for every grid cell in the tooltip.

I modified the code from the gome_raster_interactive example below to demonstrate the issue. I would like to be able to hover over the grid cell location and see the values of z in the tooltip, but this doesn't work. Thank you for any suggestions!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

df <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5)
df$z <- runif(nrow(df))

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z, tooltip = z)) +
  geom_raster_interactive()

x <- girafe(ggobj = gg)

if(interactive()) print(x)
```

Comment: @zx8754 I have the same problems? is there any feedback from ggiraph

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `geom_tile_interactive()` function to obtain the desirable results.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

df <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5)
df$z <- runif(nrow(df))

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z, tooltip = z)) +
  geom_tile_interactive()

x <- girafe(ggobj = gg)

if(interactive()) print(x)
```